# Magento admin panel stuck at menu bar

Tags: php, magento

I recently copied a magento store (ver 1.7) from live server to my local computer (both ubuntu).

Everything works fine but when I login to the admin panel, only a header displaying, the page stuck at the menu bar.

If I remove the codes in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/menu.phtml then everything works (of course there will be not menu bar).

And after I checked for a whole day, I found some core issues:

In app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Menu.php there is getMenuArray(), and it's calling $this->_buildMenuArray(), and if I var_dump before the return in function _buildMenuArray(), it's also correct. But if I var_dump in getMenuArray(), then nothing will be displayed, the code already stucked before.

I tried to check the apache error logs and magento exceptions, nothing helpful could be found.

Can anyone help me out of this ?

Comment: Try replacing your core files with those from a fresh installation of Magento.

Comment: manually delete all cache, session and locks data from /var/cache, /var/session and /var/locks. Hope will work fine after deleting.

Comment: I tried all above solutions, not working, thx